# Lisp native functions source codes

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

Is there a way to read the source code of native Lisp functions (e.g. 'merge') through Interactive Lisp Shell GNU CLisp (v 2.49) ? If there isn't what is the best (and fastest) way to get it ?

Comment: I didn't found it in my previous search. Thank you !

Comment: It list the location and describes the content of files, though I haven't found yet a method to access it via CLisp console